# Need to install a Multi-Desktop Environment on a virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, remote, multiple-desktops, multi-user

I need to install a virtual machine with seperated desktops for each user and each one with it's own customizing enabled. There should also be a separate desktop for guests with a fixed envirionment and disabled settings. Although I'm running multiple ubuntu servers, I have absolute no idea how to setup a ubuntu graphical environment. The goal is to reach a configuration like this:

```
user0 => desktop 0 => admin => accessed from everywhere (and local)
user1 => desktop 1 => user  => accessed remote only from everywhere
user2 => desktop 2 => user  => accessed remote only from everywhere
user3 => desktop 3 => guest => accessed remote only from restricted network
(I only need these four users at this time.)
```

Is that possible? And if, how can I realize this? What are the minimum requirements (RAM, HDD, etc.)

I've installed the new 14.04 desktop, but have even problems to get remote access enabled. I realized, that my knowledge is ok on the console, but with grapical things I'm a absolute beginner.

I really need help!

Regards,
Michael

Comment: Ok, my questions seems to be a little confusing. Let me give you some additional informations.

Access from everywhere means not from external, but all internal lans.

I have not problems to implement vpn or network, I have problems to realize multiple desktops on ubuntu. 

Regards, Michael

Answer (score 0):

Any installation of Ubuntu (linux) is multi-user (more than one desktop) by default.  The virtual OS is the same.

Unless you have multiple dynamic IP's by passing the host machine and logging into the guest machine from remote might be a little tricky.  I would consider it easier if you setup a VPN server.

Connect your guest machine (your virtual machine) to the vpn.  Also have your users connect to the vpn from remote. They could then connect directly to the virtual machine as if they were at the same location.

You can find easy to follow VPN setup steps at: http://faq.apollo3.com/ljames/ubuntu/vpn/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've already a functionally VPN running, but it isn't even necessary. I need remote access from LAN only.

I've been testing with xrdp and it seems to do what I need. But now my prolem is, that I see only a grey screen with an X as cursor. What I have to do next?